# Can't access Teams Toolkit menu in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, teams-toolkit

I am trying to build an app in VSCode using the Microsoft Teams Toolkit.  I already have a skeleton application and don't need to create a new one from scratch.  When I installed Teams Toolkit, I get this menu:

[image]

All the tutorials say I should have a menu where I can see things like my account, but I can't get past what seems to be a tutorial menu.  I tried going through each step in this menu, but it still doesn't display the full menu.  Any ideas?

Comment: What did you do for the "Get Started" step?

Comment: I did all the things.  They all have the blue checkmark

Comment: I had to go through all the steps again in a brand new project and then restart VSCode to make it go away.

Comment: So you found the solution to your problem? If so, (good job!) write up an answer post following the guidance written in [answer] :)

Comment: And please consider reading about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add transcriptions** of the text in your image of the menu. Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting). (tl;dr, mainly, transcriptions here can help future googlers find this Q&A)

Answer (score 0):

The button is gray means the Teams Toolkit extension is still loading, you can wait a moment to see whether it works.

If it still doesn't work, you can try to install the latest extension and try again.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TeamsDevApp.ms-teams-vscode-extension

Answer (score 0):

There are probably two errors here:

1. Your extension have problems. To test this:

- open a new VSCode window
- click on the sidebar for Teams Toolkit extension
- wait for it to load
- click "Create a New App"
- Select an Option > Bot > Basic Bot > JavaScript/TypeScript > Browse where you want to create it
- wait for it to be generated (bottom right vscode has loading info)
- you should see this picture for Teams Toolkit extension
  [working_teams_toolkit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZaBQ.png)

*** if you have this problem, reinstall back the extension

2. Your code structure doesn't follow the structure below.

[basic_structure_teams_app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvTJB.png).

If it doesn't follow that, you probably need to add something.